# Is there a way to source an encrypted (GPG) file on-the-fly in a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, gpg

I need a bash script to source a file that is encrypted, as the file being sourced contains sensitive information.

I would like the script to prompt for the GPG passphrase and then run, sourcing the encrypted file. I cannot figure out how to do this though. There must be user input for the passphrase, as I don't want to store a key on the server with the encrypted file.

Looking into some different methods, I do not want to decrypt the file, source the non-encrypted file, then delete it after. I would like to reduce the chance of leaving an non-encrypted file behind, if something went wrong in the script.

Is there a way to get the GPG output of a file to source it this way? Possibly collecting STDOUT and parsing it (if GPG can even output the contents this way).

Also, if there is another way to encrypt a file that shell scripts can use, I am not aware of it, but open to other possibilities.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this using [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst).

```
. <(gpg -qd "$encrypted_filename")
```

Here's an example:

```
% cat > to-source <<< 'echo "Hello"'
% . ./to-source                     
Hello
% gpg -e -r chris@chrisdown.name to-source
% . <(gpg -qd to-source.gpg)
Hello
```

`gpg -d` does not persist the file to disk, it just outputs it to stdout. `<()` uses a [FIFO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), which also does not result in the actual file data being written to disk.

In bash, `.` and `source` are synonyms, but `.` is more portable (it's part of POSIX), so I've used it here. Note, however, that `<()` is not as portable -- as far as I know it's only supported in bash, zsh, ksh88, and ksh93. pdksh and mksh have [coprocesses](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc) which can have the same effect.

Comment: this is a very nice solution. Thought of a named pipe, but did not want to manage it. I was not aware I could do it this way.

Comment: Of course, if you have a worry about someone being able to read a temporary FILE, with this you have the exact same worry with someone being able to read the temporary pipe created by `<(command)`.

Comment: @ZanLynx The question explicitly states that this is about not persisting on disk. The solution to doing this securely otherwise is the same as everywhere else: use a user that only you control, and do it on a system where only you have root.

Comment: You can also do this with an aescrypt encrypted file (which I did):  `. <(aescrypt -d -o - file.aes)`

Answer (score 5):

If you've got `gpg-agent` set up properly, using `pinentry-tty` or some other version that doesn't pollute stdin/stdout, then you should be able to do something like:

```
source <( gpg --decrypt file.gpg )
```

This uses process substitution to feed the result to `source` as if it's a file. The specific file data will vanish as soon as the shell is done with it, though you still need to be careful about the sensitive data in the shell's memory after that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the most sane answer has already been given, here's an insane one - use this filesystem:

https://github.com/jseppanen/gpgfs

This way your program will not notice it's talking to a pipe.

Comment: only problem is that it might need to cache the password from the gpg key...even if used with the `cache` flag of gpg, _it is_ really insane (in term of security)