# How to decrypt the file on the fly without process substitution?

Tags: shell, gpg, source-command

I need to source the file by decrypting it on the fly using the below command.

```
. <(gpg -qd "$encrypted_filename")
```

sh is not supporting process substitution. I can't use bash. Please suggest some other way.

[Is there a way to source an encrypted (GPG) file on-the-fly in a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237939/is-there-a-way-to-source-an-encrypted-gpg-file-on-the-fly-in-a-script)

Comment: Try this command: eval `gpg -d encrypted_file`

Answer (score 1):

In a *second* session:

```
mkfifo p &&
gpg -d -o p "$encrypted_filename"
# File `p' exists. Overwrite? (y/N) y
```

In your *original* session:

```
. p
rm p
```

---

To accomplish it in one session, and if you're comfortable with gpg `Assuming "yes" on most questions`, then:

```
mkfifo p &&
gpg --yes -d -o p file.gpg & 
. p &&
rm p
```

Hat tip to [Outurnate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/96540/outurnate)'s [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406008/how-to-decrypt-the-file-on-the-fly-without-process-substitution/406108?noredirect=1#comment726602_406108) reminding me of [gpg's `--yes` flag](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html).

Comment: you could do this in one session by backgrounding gpg

Comment: I wasn't able, as I needed to provide the "y" input to gpg's "overwrite?" prompt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708556/2510022

Comment: @jeff I need in one session. Basically I need to source the credentials from the encrypted configuration file. I have to add this to many scripts.so many will running parallel. Does rm file won't create issue.?

Comment: You could wrap your own protection around the `p` fifo that's created -- by making sure it does or doesn't exist beforehand, by putting it into a mktemp directory, etc. I wanted to provide self-contained steps that cleaned up after themselves; you could keep the pipe around between invocations -- just create it once, and don't delete it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller hmm .. I dont want the decrypted file to be in a physical file,

Comment: Pipes/fifo’s aren’t regular files. Create one and see!

Comment: This fifo file p is troubling . some times it is failing saying file already exists or file not exists. @JeffSchaller

Comment: Are you removing it every time, or leaving it?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSTRUCTIONS="$(gpg -qd $encrypted_filename)"
eval $INSTRUCTIONS
```

Comment: It is not working . I need to source the output of the decrypted file.